# How to test keyboard navigation with Vue?

Tags: testing, vue.js, accessibility, vue-test-utils

I'm unit-testing a component using `@vue/test-utils` which come with the Vue CLI (version 3). I want to test for keyboard interaction.

The docs [mention the keyboard](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/#testing-key-mouse-and-other-dom-events) but it seems like that only applies to actual listeners.
For example, if I have a button like

```
<button @click="trigger()">Button</button>
```

and I try to do

```
wrapper.find('button').trigger('keydown.enter')
```

that doesn't register (I think) because I never explicitly do

```
<button @keydown.enter="trigger()">Button</button>.
```

Also, it seems like I cannot navigate around with the keyboard. How do I test that [focus is trapped](https://hiddedevries.nl/en/blog/2017-01-29-using-javascript-to-trap-focus-in-an-element) in a popover menu if I cannot press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key from the tests?

[This](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/484) seems relevant but doesn't offer any solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. If you don't specify @keydown.enter, why the event should be triggered? The issue that you link provide a solution: set the value by input.element.value and then trigger the event itself. It is a bit manual but that is the way...

Comment: @MátéWiszt Because that's how browsers work. When you specify click event, that means "focus and enter" or "focus and space" as well. Also a "touch" event for touchscreen devices. Also, your other suggestion doesn't follow the principle from the Vue Test Utils docs itself: "we recommend writing tests that assert your component's public interface, and treat its internals as a black box".

Comment: So you are saying that if I am on a webpage and I hit enter, all the click events should be triggered on all buttons that have an active click listener on it? I didn't say that my suggestion follows the principle I just said that it was not true that it didn't offer any solution ;)

Comment: @MátéWiszt No, I said _focus_ and enter.